# Assign last two copied items to variables in Auto Hot Key

Tags: autohotkey

I have searched on Google and this site and perhaps my search terms are off but I can't find what I'm trying to do. I'm new to AHK but I feel this is a simple thing. Basically I want to copy one piece of text copy another, and have them written out in a hotstring. Works fine with one var but I can't figure out how to do two.

```
clip1 := clipboard

:C:etitle::
sendinput, Text [%clip1%] - %clip2%
return
```

I just want to copy first thing, copy second, go to text field and type text expansion phrase and boom there are both there, there is nothing fancy that needs to be done, copy will always be plain text, etc.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this

```
~^c::                  ; Ctrl+C to copy the selected text
    clip1 := ""        ; empty the variable clip1
    clip1 := clipboard ; save the clipboard to the variable clip1
    clipboard := ""    ; empty the clipboard (start off empty to allow ClipWait to detect when the text has arrived)
    Send, ^c           ; copy the selected text
    ClipWait 1         ; wait for the clipboard to contain data.    
    If (ErrorLevel)
        MsgBox, No text selected    
return


:C:etitle::
    sendinput, Text [%clip1%] - ^v
return
```